# Getting null while accessing initParameter in jsp

Tags: jsp, web.xml, init-parameters

I am trying to access `initParameter` in my jsp.

When I try to access the `initparameter` it is coming out as null.

My jsp page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%   
String user=config.getInitParameter("User");  
out.print("Hello "+user);  
%>  
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>
Learning</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/config.jsp</jsp-file>
<init-param>
  <param-name>User</param-name>
  <param-value>Dummy</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/config.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am getting null while accessing init parameter. Please suggest.

Comment: It's working with me, can you check your directory structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JSP file name is `config.jsp` it should work.

A case in which you can get a null value is when you write following:

```
<% String user=config.getInitParameter("User"); 
out.print("Hello "+user);%>
```

In JSP which is not **config.jsp**.

So please cross-check your JSP's name and It should be directly under WebContent in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The Name for jsp-file mentioned in the web.xml should be matched with the actual jsp file name in the WebContent
example
suppose you have /intipage.jsp in web.xml you need to carete initpage.jsp in the WebContent